# Product type not updated for a custum attribute in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom product type(test) successfully. Now i have added an attribute for catalog section in following manner.

```
$installer = $this;

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$data=array(
'type'=>'decimal',

'input'=>'text',

'label'=>'Rent Price',

'global'=>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,

'is_required'=>'0',

'is_comparable'=>'0',

'is_searchable'=>'0',

'is_unique'=>'0',

'is_configurable'=>'0',

'use_defined'=>'0',

'apply_to' => array('test')
);

$attributeId = $setup->addAttribute('catalog_product','custum_price',$data);
```

Every thing is working perfectly but this attribute is showing in every products.I have just checked the table structure and found "catalog_eav_attribute" table is showing "Null" in apply_to field for this attribute.When i edit the value of this field manually and set the value "test",attribute starts showing in test type product.
But i dont want to update in this manner.Please guide me what i have done wrong.

Comment: I found the solution.check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051305/adding-attributes-to-custom-product-only?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using attribute type, use attribute set instead. Add the attribute to only the attribute set that is required. Create product using the attribute set and other product wont show this attribute. Check for magento attribute set if you are facing some issue

Comment: Dear i am not setting the attribute type but i can set attribute set by following lines.$attributeId        =   $setup->getAttribute('catalog_product','custum_price');
$attributeSetId     =   $setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');
$attributeGroupId   =   $setup->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,'Prices');
$setup->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,$attributeGroupId['attribute_group_id'],$attributeId['attribute_id']);       But I want to show this option only for custum product type.

Comment: If you are able to set attribute set of attribute why are you not using attribute set for your custom product type. No of attributes shown for product at backend are derived from attribute set. So, try using it